# Submit and iOS App for a client that already own an App created by another developer

Tags: ios, submission, iphone-developer-program

I've developed an App for a client that already owns an application under his account.

The previous developer has sent a .p12 file to the client with the key for the distribution.

Now I'm a bit confused... what I have to do to submit my app (that is a totally different App, so not an update of their previous App) is relatedi with this p12 file?

My idea is just to create a new distribution certificate using a new CSR and then send my new CSR to the client as backup.

Is this the right way to go?

EDIT: 
The client has an account of type "company" so I could add myself to their developer account thanks to the tab "People" and I own their username and password.

I just want to know which is the most correct way to do perform a submission for a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.p12` has the certificate which are used to create the `provisioning profiles`. (.p12 file also has the keychain keys )

So you dont have to worry that using `.p12` files will update any other apps.
Provisioning files are used to sign the apps and based on that you can upload and update any app.

You just need to create a new provisioning profile with the `.p12` certificate in dev Center and use it to sign your app and submit.

Comment: So have I to use the .p12 created by the other developer? or I need to create a new one?

Comment: you can create new certificate if you have account credentials , using   only one certificate though is easier and recommended to avoid confusion later on

Comment: But how I use the p12 file? If I create a new certificate I'm asked to provide a CSR not a p12

Comment: creating new certificate means not using previous .p12 file , if you want to use the .p12 file, just import it in keychain and create new provisioning profile and upload app

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused now. You said that to use the .p12 file I import it in the Kchain. Ok, then you said that I can create a new certificate. Great! Now, how  can I connect the new certificate with the p12 in the KChain?!?!

Comment: can you come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow